# Strange characters instead national letters using Unicode in WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

My program reads text from a file and puts it in combo box. 
When the file contains text with english characters everything works fine. 
When it contains some polish letters, they are replacing with strange characters. 
The file encoding is UTF-8 (without BOM).

```
myCombo = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, (LPCWSTR)L"COMBOBOX", NULL,
                             WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | CBS_DROPDOWNLIST,
                             a, b, c, d,
                             hwnd, (HMENU)ID_COMBO, hThisInstance, NULL);

wstring foo;
wifstream bar("theTextFile.txt");
getline(bar, foo);
SendMessageW(myCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)(foo.c_str()));
```

What can I do to make my program showing correct national letters?

PS. Sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: wifstream is a maddingly silly class, the only thing that's wide about it is the name of the file you pass.  Which you fumbled in your snippet.  The actual content of the file is not considered wide, not utf-8 either.  Not without imbuing it with the right codecvt<>.  Check your CRT for a boilerplate implementation of it, something similar to "codecvt_utf8" typically.

Comment: @HansPassant `std::wifstream` does not accept a wide string as a filename. Microsoft's implementation does as an extension, but this is unrelated to wide streams; Even their narrow fstream classes accept wide string filenames. They do this simply because their file API is broken with narrow strings.

Comment: The purpose of wide streams is not to operate on data stored as wide characters, but to make the conversion between internal and external representations invisible to the programmer. This only problem is that fixed-width codepoint representations turned out to be worthless for their intended purpose (i.e., keeping international text processing as simple as processing english ascii text), so nobody uses wide characters in the way they were intended to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wifstream` won't read UTF-8 text on Windows by default. The `codecvt` facet in the stream's locale is what converts from the bytes in the file into `wchar_t`, so you need to set this such that it will do the conversion to `wchar_t` you want.

Something like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <locale>  // std::locale
#include <codecvt> // std::codecvt_utf8_utf16
#include <memory>  // std::unique_ptr

#include <Windows.h> // WriteConsoleW

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::wstring foo;
    std::wifstream bar("theTextFile.txt");

    typedef std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10FFFF, std::consume_header> codecvt;
    std::unique_ptr<codecvt> ptr(new codecvt);
    std::locale utf8_locale((std::locale()), ptr.get());
    ptr.release();
    bar.imbue(utf8_locale);

    std::getline(bar, foo);

    DWORD n;
    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), foo.c_str(), foo.size(), &n, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Right. The default conversion is from your system code page. Why Windows doesn't move to the 21st century and let you use UTF-8 for a code page is beyond me.

Comment: UTF-8 is a code page (65001). [But it can't be the ANSI code page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2007/01/03/1392379.aspx).